# Permission denied for symbolic link

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, permission, symlink

I'm creating a symbolic link with the following applescript:

```
on run
    do shell script "rm /usr/bin/ant" with administrator privileges
    do shell script "ln -s /Users/hordine/software/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant /usr/bin/ant" with administrator privileges
end run
```

The symbolic link is created but when I try to execute `ant -version` from a terminal window, I get a permission denied error.

How can I create this link so that I DO have permission to execute it later?

Comment: Which access permissions are set for `/Users/hordine/software/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a `chmod` on the symlink to give you the rights.

```
do shell script "chmod 755 /usr/bin/ant" with administrator privileges
```